# Heroku Rails ClearDB Resque Connections

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

If I have 20 different jobs in Resque, does that mean that my ClearDB database would potential have 20+ connections? How can I monitor how many connections my ClearDB is using?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how many jobs you have in Resque. It matters how many workers you have running. In Resque, each worker runs in a separate process and hence opens its own connection to the database.

If the number of connections is a concern, you can try using [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) instead. Sidekiq is API-compatible with Resque, but its workers run in threads in a single process. This way, you should be able to use a shared connection pool to manage how many connections are open at the same time.

Comment: which one is going to scale better? would i rather have 30 connections to my db in different workers, or multiple threads in a single fat process?

Comment: That all depends. :) If you're doing lots of IO and your code is thread-safe, stick them all in one process using Sidekiq to minimize memory usage. If you're using lots of CPU, each worker should have its own dedicated process. Hope that helps.